# Нужен коммерческий (бесплатный) компилятор

Tags: ide, c++

Пользуюсь Visual studio уже года 1.5. Все радует, если не одно - она платная. Так как в других IDE не работал и не знаю, какая лучше и более похожа на студию (библиотеками).  Вчера пробовал  gcc, там нет библиотеки iostream.h. Как я понял, там проект не соберешь, только 1 файл компилировать можно. Какую IDE мне выбрать?

Требования:

1. Графическая среда.
2. Максимальное сходство с VS.
3. Если уж не бесплатный, то хотя бы дешевле VS.

Также интересует IDE для C#.

Comment: g++, а не gcc

Answer (score 4):

Во-первых, пиши просто

```
#include <iostream>
```

, потому что

```
#include <iostream.h>
```

-- устаревшая, нерекомендуемая конструкция.

Во-вторых, для компиляции C++ нужно запускать не gcc, а g++. И будет тебе iostream.

Comment: а если хочется использовать gcc то 
gcc -x c++ -lstdc++ filename.cpp

Answer (score 4):

Для C# связки лучше чем Visual Studio + ReSharper не найти к сожалению.
Но тут есть 3 варианта:

- Express версия, бесплатна, для некоммерческого использования, но и функционал урезан немного.
- DreamSpark — если студент, можешь получить бесплатно Professional версию и использовать её в любых проектах.
- BizSpark — если молодой стартап/бизнес, можешь попробовать получить доступ к этой программе. В замен получишь **весь** софт MS бесплатно на 3 года, по окончании должен будешь заплатить всего 100$, при этом весь софт сможешь продолжать использовать легально, новый придется покупать.

Для C++ есть целая гора бесплатных, опенсорсных и кроссплатформенных IDE, из самых мощных это пожалуй: NetBeans и Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Направлю вас в сторону clang, gcc и других opensource проектов все они по возможностям не уступают студии, легко интегрируются с другими ide - такими как eclipse, anjuta, qtcreator и др. и являются бесплатными. В альтернативной ОС есть mingw эта ide похожа на vsC++ 6 и ипользует gcc.
Очень советую попробовать clang он хорошо отображает найденные в коде ошибки и даже предлагает варианты по их исправлению(иногда). 
Если вы считаете себя довольно продвинутым кодером можете поробовать молодой pcc, его фишка
в том что его делают как можно ближе к стандарту языка.
Ну gcc - это классика, очень хороший компилятор советую за основу взять все-же его.

Что касается ide тут очень тяжелый вопрос, некоторые используют текстовый редактор + makefiles, некоторые полноценные ide, тут нужно выбирать в зависимости от того для чего вы будете программировать. Если для работы берите что помощнее, если для учебы, берите что по "проще"(emacs, vim).

P.S: многие пользователи альтернативной ОС не видят разницы между ide и компилятором что всегда улыбает...

Comment: Большое спасибо!!!простите тупанул написал iostream.h ))

Answer (score 1):

[SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/)

[Visual C# 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-CS)

[MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/Download)

[C# Plugin for Eclipse](http://www.improve-technologies.com/alpha/esharp/)

[SlickEdit](http://www.slickedit.com/)

из непроверенных:

[xacc](http://xacc.wordpress.com/)

[онлайн компилятор](http://compilr.com/)

[Borland Turbo C#](http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2438988)

[C# Studio](http://csharp-studio.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

С позиции сегодняшнего дня, есть [бесплатная Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/ru/free-developer-offers/).

Согласно [лицензии](https://www.visualstudio.com/ru/license-terms/mlt553321/), она допускает коммерческую разработку для самостоятельных разработчиков и для маленьких коллективов, содержащих не более 5 программистов и тестеров.

(С другой стороны, если ваш коллектив больше, то ваш продукт зарабатывает приличные деньги, и купить коммерческую версию Visual Studio не должно быть проблемой.)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2010 Express к вашим услугам!

А также студентам можно получить бесплатную копию VS 2010 Professional. Уже получил!

Comment: на торрентах можно легко найти msdn образ ultimate, не требующий активации

Comment: На торрентах можно что угодно найти, вопрос не в том как активировать студию.

Comment: а я и не отвечал как активировать студию, я просто сказал что можно найти бесплатную версию ultimate. А если вы хотите платить за неё - дело ваше

Comment: Ну используйте эту "бесплатную" версию на предприятии, потом платить будете уже налоговой.